# How to make my fuction return a step count

Tags: functions, function-construction, random, counting

I am new to mathematica, and I have this 3d random walker program which runs with a fixed (given) amount of steps. What I want it to do is to run forever but stop when two walkers collide (aka have the same position). When it stops it should return the number of steps before the collision. So I am planning on having that function to be in loop which in Java/C might look similar to this:

```
for (i = 0; i < times_to_run; i++) 
{ 
    total = total + randomWalker(args..);
}


Clear[randomWalk3D]
randomWalk3D[steps_Integer, start_, region_] /;
  start \[Element] region := 

  ...

  x = 0; v = {}; For[i = 1, i < steps, i++,
     If[{positions[[i]]} == {positions2[[i]]}, x++; AppendTo[v, i],]

    ]
   Manipulate [
    Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5, Gray], region, AbsolutePointSize[10], 
      Cyan, Line[positions], Red, Line[positions2], 
      pointPrimitives[i], pointPrimitives2[i]}, text[i], 
     ImagePadding -> 5, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", Gray}}], {i, 1, 
     Length[positions], 1}]
   Print["Number of collisions: ", x]
   Print["Collision at i = ", v]

  ]
randomWalk3D[1000, {4, 4, 4}, Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {10, 10, 10}]]
```

https://github.com/tabilzad/Random/blob/master/RandomW.nb

Comment: Please post your mathematica code

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Do you want the number of steps only or an actual animation?

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply! I posted the link to my code. I don't care so much about the animation... but numbers is whats more important

Comment: @Dr.belisarius see above

Comment: Please take your time for browsing the site and take a look at how people post code here

Comment: @Dr.belisarius I know how to post code, I just thought it is more convenient to post a link due to code's size. Thank you

Comment: Ok, But I'm downvoting untl you try to post  a minimal example in plain text. Detecting malicious code in `.nb` format is just too time consuming

Comment: @Dr.belisarius done

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In 2D:

```
SeedRandom[3];
pos1 = {0, 0};
pos2 = {4, 4};
rc := RandomChoice[{-1, 0, 1}, {2, 2}]
l = Transpose@NestWhileList[# + rc &, {pos1, pos2}, Unequal @@ # &];
Print@Length@l[[1]];
ListLinePlot@l
(*32*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Perhaps the following is better for visualization

```
graph[s_, col_] := Module[{rul, edges},
  rul = Thread[Rule[Union@s, Range@Length@Union@s]];
  edges = Rule @@@ (Partition[s, 2, 1] /. rul); 
  GraphPlot[edges, VertexCoordinateRules -> Reverse /@ rul, MultiedgeStyle -> 1/7, 
   EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({col, Arrowheads[Small], Arrow[#1]} &)]]

Show @@ MapThread[graph, {l, {Red, Green}}, 1]
```

[image]